# Laravel 5.2 mime type validation not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working with the Laravel validation with mime type for image validation. But mime type validation is not validating images.

Here is the validation code

```
$this->validate($request, [            
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);
```

This is validation script, and here is submission form details.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class=" col-sm-12">
   {!! Form::file('image', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
      @if ($errors->has('image')) <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('image') }}</span> @endif
  </div>   </div>
```

Required validation working well, but when I tying to use mime validation it is not working. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: What does it mean "it is not working"? It's returns error for correct data? It returns OK for invalid data?

Comment: I mean to say that required validation is working for image field, but validation is not working with mimes type with images parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line I think it will be work

```
'mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg,image/gif,image/svg'
```